# $\int_0^1 \frac{dr}{r\log^n(1+\frac{1}{r})}< \infty$ if $n>1$

Tags: calculus

In showing $u(x)=\log\log(1+|x|)$ is $W^{1,n}(B(0,1)) $ but not in $L^\infty(B(0,1))$ for $n>1$. I found $|\nabla u|\leq \frac{1}{r\log(1+\frac{1}{r})}$ where $r=|x|$ and I calculate the $L^n$ norm of $|\nabla u|$
\begin{align*}
\int_{(B(0,1))}|\nabla u|^n
&\leq \int_{(B(0,1))}\frac{1}{|x|^n\log^n(1+\frac{1}{|x|})}\\
&= \int_0^1\frac{1}{r^n\log^n(1+\frac{1}{r})}r^{n-1}dr\\
&= \int_0^1\frac{dr}{r\log^n(1+\frac{1}{r})}
\end{align*}
Hence, I can enclose the proof by showing $\int_0^1 \frac{dr}{r\log^n(1+\frac{1}{r})}< \infty$. But I got stuck here. Indeed, $\frac{1}{\log^n(1+\frac{1}{r})}$ should decrease very fast near $0$. But I have no idea how to show the resut.

Answer (score 3):

Write $\int_0^1=\int_0^{1/2}+\int_{1/2}^1$ and use $$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dr}{r\log^n(1+1/r)}<\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dr}{r\log^n(1/r)}=\frac{\log^{1-n}2}{n-1}$$ (the remaining integral is clearly finite).

Comment: I see, thank you!